# Device tree-like structure for Linux driver

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I'm trying to build a structure that is similar to a device tree. Basically, i want to get a driver that is built to work with a device tree, to work the same way without it. I want to build the wrapper and the structure that contain all the information a device tree has, and pass it onto the driver.

Anyone has any idea how i can do this or a good place to read abut it? i looked for it but couldn't find anything or any example of something similar on how to do this.

Best regards and thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's already been done in the kernel recently and called unified device property API, in particularly it supports same properties come from DeviceTree, ACPI, or built-in in the platform code. More information about API you may find in the sources *include/linux/property.h*, *drivers/base/property.c*. The one of the examples is rfkill_gpio driver, i.e. *net/rfkill/rfkill-gpio.c* [consumer], *arch/arm/mach-tegra/board-paz00.c* [provider].

Comment: I checked what you told me, and i noticed that, that API only went to the mainline on kernel 3.19. Unfortunately for me, i need to develop this for kernel 3.18. Do you know any way i can do his without using that API?

Comment: Backporting from 3.19 to 3.18.y might be not a big deal.